# Phonegap fixed width issues

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I have a webapp with fixed width layout at 1280px.
I need to adapt this webapp for mobile.
Basically I need to fill the whole device screen width with 1280px by scaling acordingly.
I managed to do this by using viewport meta tag with fixed width.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1280, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0"/>
```

It works great in mobile chrome browser.

Now I need to wrap this webapp inside mobile app.
I picked Phonegap, but as it turned out it won't work as good as chrome browser did.
It doesn't do any scaling, everything is huge.

How can I get it to work? Is it even possible with phonegap to scale fixed layout accordingly in order to fill the screen, without breaking the layout? Or maybe there's any better alternative to phonegap?

Answer (score 0):

What i understand, you have a fixed width, so thats the problem.

1280 is also a lot :)

I suggest that you build your site with a responsive framework eg. http://jquerymobile.com/

I always use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```